# How to decode JSON and faithfully represent backslashes in Python using the json library

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have a config file which I'm trying to pull apart and then reassemble with updated sections. The config file is in a json format, and I'm trying to extract components of it out to update before inserting back into another json file.

The problem I'm finding is that sections of the JSON file use `"\/"` which when decoded using the JSON library for python I get `"/"` coming out. I need to faithfully represent the original JSON once I insert the updated values back into the new JSON file, hence I need the missing `"\/"`.

I suspect the `\` is getting interpreted as an escape and being dropped by the JSON decoder.

Below is a sample of my efforts so far:

JSON string example:

```
{"Markup\/0.xaml":"text\/xml; charset=utf-8; format=xml; clrtype=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic","Markup\/1.xaml":"text\/xml; charset=utf-8; format=xml; clrtype=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic"}
```

Python Code:

```
import json
with open(full_json_path_old, 'r+') as fo:
    data = json.load(fo) 
    print "DECODED STRING - ", data
```

Result of the Print:

```
u'Markup/0.xaml': u'text/xml; charset=utf-8; format=xml; clrtype=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic',
u'Markup/1.xaml': u'text/xml; charset=utf-8; format=xml; clrtype=ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Graphic'
```

Comment: Why do you think you need to get `\/` in Python? That'd be **very surprising**, as the backslash is correctly interpreted as an escape character. I'm surprised the forward slashes are escaped however, they are strictly speaking not needed for the value to be interpreted correctly.

Comment: I can see the format of the JSON string, yes. It is correct and valid JSON, and the interpretation by the JSON decoder is correct and valid too. You'd get the same value in any other compliant JSON decoder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `\` backslash is an escape character, and a proper JSON decoder will honour such a character as an escape. The Python JSON decoder is no exception. See [section 7 of RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7):

> Any character may be escaped.

and

> ```
> char = unescaped /
>     escape (
>         %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
>         %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
>         %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
>         %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
>         %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
>         %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
>         %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
>         %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
>         %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX
>
> escape = %x5C              ; \
> ```

(so the `\/` sequence is the *escape solidus* sequence).

Your output is **correct**; in that I would expect mimetype components like `text` and `xml` to be delimited by a forward slash, not by `\/`.

A forward slash (solidus in the standard) does not *have* to be escaped however. The same section 7 states what characters *must* be escaped:

> All Unicode characters may be placed within the
> quotation marks, except for the characters that must be escaped:
> quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000
> through U+001F).

As such, the Python JSON encoder won't escape a forward slash when producing JSON output.

Comment: I'm just worried that after I've updated the relevant sections in Python,when I go to insert the changes into a fresh json file using the json.dumps function the "backslash & forward slash" wont be represented correctly and the changes wont be in the correct format?

Comment: @Carps: yes, that's correct, because the backslash is not strictly needed.

Comment: Hopefully that is the case ;) Cheers for the sanity check

Comment: Not just hopefully; I quoted the relevant part of the JSON RFC. :-) *Any* character may be escaped, but only control characters, quotes and the escape character itself *must* be escaped.

Comment: So does that mean that the backslashes are just extra characters that aren't needed in the json config file?

Comment: @Carps: a forward slash is not a quote, a backslash or a control character so it doesn't need to be escaped, no. Anywhere you see `\/`, you can write `/` instead.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying Martijn, much appreciated :)